# How to select by 1 xbar date/second in kdb+

Tags: pandas, kdb

I am trying to run a select on a table whereby the data in the table ranges across multiple days, thus it does not conform to daily data that [the documentation](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/xbar/) eludes to.
Application of the xbar selection accross multiple days obviously results in data that is not ordered i.e. select last size, last price by 1 xbar time.second on data that includes 2 days would result in:

```
second   | size price
====================
00:00:01 | 400  555.5
00:00:01 | 600  606.0
00:00:02 | 400  555.5
00:00:02 | 600  606.0
```

How can one add the current date in the selection such that the result like what is done in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can still be orderly across multiple days e.g: `2019-09-26 16:34:40`
Furthermore how does one achieve this whilst maintaining a date format that is compatible with pandas once stored in csv?

Answer (score 4):

NB: It is easiest for us to assist you if you provide code that can replicate a sample of the kind of table that you are working with. Otherwise we need to make assumptions about your data.

Assuming that your time column is of [timestamp](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/#datatypes) type (e.g. `2019.09.03D23:11:54.711811000`), a simple solution is to `xbar` by one as a timespan, rather than using the `time.second` syntax:

```
select last size, last price by 0D00:00:01 xbar time from data
```

Using `xbar` keeps the time column as a timestamp rather than casting it to second type.

If your time column is of some other temporal type then you can still use this method if you have a date column in your table that you can use to cast time to a timestamp. This would look something like:

```
select last size, last price by 0D00:00:01 xbar date+time from data
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to group by both `date` and `second`, and the sum them

```
update time: date+time from 
    select last size, last price 
        by date: `date$time, time: 1 xbar `second$time from data
```

Or the other shorter and more efficient option is to sum date and second right in the group clause:

```
select last size, last price by time: (`date$time) + 1 xbar `second$time from data
```